# How do you stream data like Twitter's API with Node.js

Tags: node.js, socket.io

The title probably isn't the best but I apologize but while I was playing around with the Twitter API. I found something cool. They have an endpoint you can make a request to for users to listen for tweets and I was wondering how are they doing that so I could implement that in my own application. I have an educated guess on how they're doing it but I'm not 100% sure and will appreciate if anyone can tell me if i'm right or wrong and tell me if you know. IDK if this is correct but I would think when a request gets made to the API endpoint on a specific route. Since the request and response object are streams. I feel like they're just sending writing to the client with the data without actually ending the response stream, but how they know when a tweet comes in to write to the response stream if that was the case?

Comment: Possibly WebSockets? Otherwise, they are using a long-poling and leaving the connection open until there's a new tweet.

Comment: I was thinking web sockets too. That would make sense but I'm going to wait for more answers. I appreciate the response.

Comment: They actually use a simple long lived http connection. That's quite easy in nodejs.